# Symfony2 initialize service

Tags: symfony

i use a bundle (wa72/jsonrpc-bundle) as a service. I need to initialize a value just after the service is constructed, for all the application. I don't think i need a listener as i just need to set it once, not before each request.
here's what i need to do :

```
$wa72_jsonrpc = $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('wa72_jsonrpc.jsonrpccontroller');            
$wa72_jsonrpc->setSerializationContext(SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());
```

how can i do this for all the application, just 1 time ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628753/symfony-instantiate-a-service-one-time-and-use-it-with-several-users/29628982#29628982 this should help

Comment: not exactly what i need. I don't have cross session problem, and i don't ned persistent data. I just need to set the SerializationContext once, and that's all.

Comment: no, just one time, just after the service is instanciated.

Comment: so you need to check my answer better. In php every request is separate thread so you need to have some kind of persistence. But I'm afraid that when it comes to object initialization you can't achieve what you want as service is instanciated on each request

Comment: hi @user2733521 have you already see my answer? It should be possible to enable this features as a bundle settings

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, a Kernel onRequest listener would do it if you want to expose the thing to every controller with no additional work.

Another way to do it, is to setup another Service that explicitly wraps your setup and exposes it to your app as a service

src/AppBundle/Services/jsonrpcService.php:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Services;

class jsonrpcService
{
    public $jsonrpc;

    public function __construct($wa72_jsonrpc)
    {
        $wa72_jsonrpc->setSerializationContext(SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());
        $this->jsonrpc = $wa72_jsonrpc;
    }
}
```

app/config/config.yml

```
services:
    jsonrpc:
        class:        AppBundle\Services\jsonrpcService
        arguments:    [@wa72_jsonrpc.jsonrpccontroller]
```

in any controller just call:

```
$jsonrpc = $this->get('jsonrpc')->jsonrpc;
```

Comment: i can't wrap it in another service, i should have to rewrite the way the jsonrpc service is called everywhere in the app. I also don't need to init my serializationContext before all controller. I just need to do it once, at the begining and i'm done.

Comment: then do it in app.php and app_dev.php and good luck?

Answer (score 0):

Is not so well documented but you should enable it in the bundle section in the `config.yml` as described [here](https://github.com/wasinger/jsonrpc-bundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst)

> If you use jms_serializer you can also configure exclusion strategies
>   (groups, version, or max depth checks) :

```
# app/config/config.yml
wa72_json_rpc:
    functions:
        myfunction1:
            service: "mybundle.servicename"
            method: "methodofservice"
            jms_serialization_context:
                group: "my_group"
                version: "1"
                max_depth_checks: true
```

Of course, seem you need to enable the [jms serializer bundle](https://github.com/wasinger/jsonrpc-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) also.

Hope this help